# get a value from ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi can anyone help me?
I'm a little bit new with angular, i'm attempting to get a string from this model:

```
<select color="black" ng-model="select" class="styled-select"
    ng-options="provincia as provincia for provincia in province|orderBy:'toString()'"></select>
```

precisly i need to fullfill a var in the controller with the select result.
example

```
var something=$scope.select;
```

the ng-option works and it's fullfill with a list of string,what can i do?.
There i link a js feedle to make the things more clear.
http://jsfiddle.net/EeL9y/59/

thanks for the answer till now, i have to precise that i need to use that var in another function, not in the html, the url bind is there only to test if the var have gain the value.

Comment: What's the result of `$scope.select` ?

Comment: the resutl is empty, and i need to have the selection like result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a fiddle for the select and found this one and updated it slightly to showcase ng-model when you want to select something.

http://jsfiddle.net/EeL9y/55/

I think a watch in the controller will do the trick for you something like this:

```
 $scope.$watch("select",function(){
    var something=$scope.select;
});
```

UPDATE:

I have updated the fiddle as per your requirement:  http://jsfiddle.net/EeL9y/61/

Added name and value attribute to your list and traversed the selected object

Comment: i have update the fiddle link to let you see my problem<br>http://jsfiddle.net/EeL9y/58/<br>as you can see, when i changge the selection, nothing appears. Maybe with these examples the ideas is more clear, i'll edit the post with the link

Comment: it seems work, exscuse my ignorance but can you explain me the function of console.log? thank you anyway

Comment: Though this works, it really is not the way you should handle such things in angular. The `$scope` is there for a reason. You should only rely on `$watch` if the normal two-way-data-binding is not working. Using `$watch` to just set a variable is basically the exact thing two-way-data-binding is meant to do.

Comment: console.log is to see the variable value. @Yoshi you are absolutely correct. However the problem statement that he wants to set something in the controller, hence this way. However Your answer is also correct

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating things, just let angular do the magic:

**view:**

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="search()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="toSearch">

    <select
      ng-model="city"
      ng-options="city for city in cities|orderBy:'toString()'"
    ></select>

    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="search">
  </form>

  next holiday i will go to {{city}}
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
SearchCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.cities= ['Madrid', 'Dublin', 'Paris','Moscow'];
  $scope.city = 'Paris';

  $scope.search = function search() {
    // use the scope variable
    console.log(
      'searching for: "' + $scope.toSearch + '" with', $scope.city, 'selected'
    );
  };
}
```

**demo:**

http://jsbin.com/gucubaju/4/

Comment: If only the problem could be so simple:( my need is to use that var in another function:(

Comment: @mautrok that's not a problem at all, just use `$scope.city`. (see the update)